# Is there a better way to print this pattern in python using while loop only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, jupyter-notebook

i have coded in python to print this pattern, but i realise that this isn't the ideal way though. Could you guys help me out with an ideal way to print this out?.

the pattern to be printed is

1
11
202
3003
40004

the code that i have executed is also attached

```
n =int(input())
i = 1
if n ==1:
    print('1')
elif n==2:
    print('1')
    print('11')
else:
    if i ==1:
        print('1')
    while i<=n:
        j=1
        while j<=i+1:
            if j==1 or j==i+1:
                print(i,end='')
            else:
                print('0',end='')
            j=j+1
        print()
        i=i+1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(1, *[f'{i}{"0"*(i-1)}{i}' for i in range(1, 5)], sep='\n')
```

Comment: this was helpful. Thank you so much. could you help me out with printing this pattern with only while loop?

Comment: I would write:

    `print(1)
    i = 1
    while i < 5:
        print(f'{i}{"0"*(i-1)}{i}')
        i += 1`

Comment: this was helpful! Thank you mate!

Answer (score 1):

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        if i==1:
            print("1",end='')
        elif j==1 or j==i:
            print(i-1,end='')
        else:
            print(0,end='')
        j=j+1
    print()
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more pythonic:

```
>>> for i in [str(x) + (x-1)*'0' + str(x) for x in range(1,10)]:
...     print(i)
```

Comment: this was helpful. Thank you so much. could you help me out with printing this pattern with only while loop?